# Coinbase Android SDK Sending Bitcoin Issue

Tags: android, coinbase-api

I'm using this dependency `compile ('com.coinbase.android:coinbase-android-sdk:1.0.1')`

I'm trying to send bitcoin (after OAuth2 token)

using:

```
Transaction t = new Transaction();
t.setTo("emailAddressToSend");
t.setAmount(Money.parse("BTC 0.001"));
t.setNote("notes to send");
cb = new CoinbaseBuilder().withAccessToken(tokens.getAccessToken()).build();
cb.sendMoney(t);
```

but it returns

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://coinbase.com/api/v1/transactions/send_money
```

in Manifest all required permissions are available like INTERNET Permission.
Any idea whats the problem?

Comment: Hello, I am getting same issue, did you found any solution? or any other way?

Comment: Sorry buddy Coinbase support is totally failed to resolve this issue even they does not response.